# Python: Making Pickle files more secure?

Tags: python, pickle

In my Python program I have used the Pickle module in order to save user definitions and then load them back up the next they run the program. Now from what I understand from the UsingPickle article on the Python Wiki website is that the Pickle files are likely to be hacked etc. making it insecure.

I've noticed that the Pickle files are often just left in the directory that the Python script is in. Is there a way to make these files more secure and hidden away from sight? If so, how would this affect me using cx_Freeze on my script when including the Pickle file in the setup script?

```
import pickle

terms = pickle.load(open("save.p", "rb"))

def print_menu():
    print('Computing Terms')
    print()
    print('0. Quit')
    print('1. Look Up a Term')
    print('2. Add a Term')
    print('3. Redefine a Term')
    print('4. Delete a Term')
    print('5. Display All Terms')

while True:
    print_menu()
    print()
    choice = input('Choice: ')
    if choice == '0':
        break
    elif choice == '1':
        print('\n')
        term = input('Type in a term you wish to see: ')
        if term in terms:
            definition = terms[term]
            print('\n')
            print(term, '-', definition, '\n')
            print()
            print('----------------------------------------------------------------')
            print()
            print()
        else:
            print('This term does not exist. Try adding it instead.\n')
            print()
            print('----------------------------------------------------------------')
            print()
            print()
    elif choice == '2':
        print('\n')
        term = input('What term would you like to add?: ')
        if term not in terms:
            print('\n')
            definition = input('What\'s the definition?: ')
            terms[term] = definition
            pickle.dump(terms, open("save.p", "wb"))
            print('\n')
            print(term, 'has been added.\n')
            print()
            print('----------------------------------------------------------------')
            print()
            print()
        else:
            print('\n')
            print('Term already exists, try redefining it instead.\n')
            print()
            print('----------------------------------------------------------------')
            print()
            print()
    elif choice == '3':
        print('\n')
        term = input('Which term do you want to redefine?: ')
        if term in terms:
            definition = input('What\'s the new definition?: ')
            terms[term] = definition
            pickle.dump(terms, open("save.p", "wb"))
            print('\n')
            print(term, 'has been redefined.\n')
            print()
            print('----------------------------------------------------------------')
            print()
            print()
        else:
            print('\n')
            print('That term doesn\'t exist, try adding it instead.')
            print()
            print('----------------------------------------------------------------')
            print()
            print()
    elif choice == '4':
        print('\n')
        term = input('Which term would you like to delete?: ')
        if term in terms:
            del terms[term]
            pickle.dump(terms, open("save.p", "wb"))
            print('\n')
            print('The term has been deleted.\n')
            print()
            print('----------------------------------------------------------------')
            print()
            print()
        else:
            print('\n')
            print('This term doesn\'t exist.')
            print()
            print('----------------------------------------------------------------')
            print()
            print()
    elif choice == '5':
        print('\n')
        print('The terms available are: ')
        print()
        for term in sorted(terms):
            print(term)
        print()
        print()
        print('----------------------------------------------------------------')
        print()
        print()
    else:
        print('\n')
        print('Sorry, but ', choice, ' is not a valid choice.\n')
        print()
        print('----------------------------------------------------------------')
        print()
        print()
```

Answer (score 6):

If your concern is users being able to inject arbitrary code into the program easily, your best bet would be to switch to another storage format that *only* stores the data type you want, such as JSON, XML, MsgPack, etc.

If your concern is users being able to change the value easily and thus breaking program logic (e.g cheating in a game) however, you should consider encrypting the user definitions file.

Anything given to the client should be considered insecure. You should always validate data on load.

Comment: Is JSON inherently more secure? [The documentation for jsonpickle](http://jsonpickle.github.io/) says, "**Warning:** Loading a JSON string from an untrusted source represents a potential security vulnerability. jsonpickle makes no attempt to sanitize the input." Wouldn't the security or lack thereof for JSON and the others be a function of how they are used?

Comment: @kuzzooroo JSON is a data format. It is only a way to organise and store data. How the application handles and (ab)uses data formats has nothing to do with the data format itself. From what I can see jsonpickle attempts to add pickle functionality to JSON, which means you can well be `eval()`ing raw, untrusted code when you `decode()` things; this is why they added a security note.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to hide the pickled file you can name it `.save.p` instead of `save.p`. This will hide it when using the default file manager on MacOS.

If your users are clever than that, you should encrypt the pickled file. Here is a tutorial on [file encryption in Python](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/06/25/aes-encryption-of-files-in-python-with-pycrypto/). This will add a layer of security but will not secure it completely since you still need to make sure the encryption key is unreachable.

Regarding the setup process, I don't think it should affect it. You just need to make sure you have the required file permissions for the pickled file.

Comment: The . trick doesn't work in Windows (nor does the $ trick work in UNIX, but still)

Comment: Not really much of a solution